# Jest scope error in mocking Aws-sdk: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'variable_name' before initialization

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, aws-sdk

I am trying to mock aws-sdk using Jest testing framework.

Here is the code I'm trying to test in my auth.js file:

```
...
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ region: config.awsConfig.region });
...
const cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
await cognito.confirmSignUp(params).promise();
....
```

Here is the testing code in my auth.spec.js file:

```
const mockConfirmSignUp = jest.fn((params) => {
  return {
    promise() {
      return Promise.resolve('mock response');
    }
  };
});

jest.mock('aws-sdk', () => {
  return {
    CognitoIdentityServiceProvider: jest.fn(() => ({
      confirmSignUp: mockConfirmSignUp
    })),
    config: {
      update: jest.fn()
    }
  };
});
```

However, when I test the code, I receive this error:

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'mockConfirmSignUp' before initialization
```

I can make it work by moving the `mockConfirmSignUp` implementation inside the `jest.mock` block, however, I want to modify the implementation of `mockConfirmSignUp` in a subsequent case to return `Promise.reject` using `mockConfirmSignUp.mockImplementationOnce()` utility in jest, for testing failure cases, and moving this function inside the jest.mock block would prohibit me from doing that.

I realize this may be 'hoisting' issue where jest.mock gets hoisted at the top of the file, however another similar test case below worked for my without any issue:

```
const mockSendEmail = jest.fn(() => {
  return {
    promise() {
      return Promise.resolve('mock response');
    }
  };
});

jest.mock('aws-sdk', () => {
  return {
    SES: jest.fn(() => ({
      sendEmail: mockSendEmail
    })),
    config: {
      update: jest.fn()
    }
  };
});
```

How is the latter code different than the former one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In resulting code `jest.mock` is hoisted above relevant auth.js `import`, both are above  `const mockConfirmSignUp` variable declaration.

The first snippet accesses `mockConfirmSignUp` at the time when `CognitoIdentityServiceProvider` is called, this happens when auth.js is imported and before `mockConfirmSignUp` declaration. The second snippet doesn't do that.

This is the situation that [the manual](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmockdocsenjest-objectjestmockmodulename-factory-options-with-the-module-factory-parameter) describes:

> A limitation with the factory parameter is that, since calls to jest.mock() are hoisted to the top of the file, it's not possible to first define a variable and then use it in the factory. An exception is made for variables that start with the word 'mock'. It's up to you to guarantee that they will be initialized on time!

A safe recipe to avoid this problem with hoisting is to move a spy from outer scope to to mocked exports in order to access it to change the implementation and assert it, this way it can be accessed on module object:

```
import awssdk from 'awssdk';

jest.mock('aws-sdk', () => {
  const mockConfirmSignUp = jest.fn(...);

  return {
    mockConfirmSignUp,
    CognitoIdentityServiceProvider: jest.fn(() => ({
      confirmSignUp: mockConfirmSignUp
    })),
    config: {
      update: jest.fn()
    }
  };
});

...
expect(awssdk.mockConfirmSignUp).toBeCalledWith(...);
```

It's also applicable when there's no problem with hoisting but a reusable mock needs to be moved from `jest.mock` to `__mocks__`.

> I can make it work by moving the mockConfirmSignUp implementation inside the jest.mock block, however, I want to modify the implementation of mockConfirmSignUp in a subsequent case to return Promise.reject using mockConfirmSignUp.mockImplementationOnce() utility in jest

If a module needs to be tested multiple times with different dependencies, auth.js and aws-sdk imports could be moved to from top level to tests. This way there would be no problem with `jest.mock` hoisting and `mockConfirmSignUp`. Also reimports require the use of `jest.resetModules` or jest.isolateModules`.

Comment: This was the exact solution I was looking for. 
In the latter code, the main js file was doing `AWS.SES({ apiVersion: config.awsConfig.sesApiVersion }).sendEmail(params).promise();` in the same line, which is why hoisting was not an issue, while in this case, first I am doing `const cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();`, and then `await cognito.confirmSignUp(params).promise();` inside the function separately!

Answer (score 0):

I create this code and it work very well (very simple):

```js
const mockedApiPost = jest.fn();

jest.mock('../../services/api', () => ({
  post: () => {
    mockedApiPost.call(mockedApiPost);
  },
}));
```